# Turn ON Screen programmatically on Android

Tags: android, screen, powermanager

I need to programmatically turn the screen on when the user turns off with power button, and yes I always have the correct flags in the `Activity` to keep screen on, but it does not avoid user pressing power button.

So far I've found a solution but it uses a **deprecated wakelock**

```
sWakeLock = sPM.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, TAG_WAKELOCK);

sWakeLock.acquire();
sWakeLock.release();
```

There is a better way to achieve it?

Comment: So the user has given a clear, unambiguous signal that they want the screen turned off, but you know better? This sounds like a dreadful user interface.

Comment: The screen should be always on, and I want to prevent accidental power button press in specific situations

Answer (score 18):

In Lollipop you might want to add some more flags:

```
final Window win = getWindow();
    win.addFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON );
```

I got this from the AOSP https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/dfd1960/src/com/android/deskclock/alarms/AlarmActivity.java

Comment: Happy to help! And greedy me - please mark my answer as correct? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not the person who made the question. I just saw it worked, up voted and said thanks

Answer (score 11):

Here is the latest way to **Turn On Screen** from an activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
    this.setTurnScreenOn(true);
} else {
    final Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

Use [FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON) but this flag has been deprecated in API level 27 so use [Activity.setTurnScreenOn(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setTurnScreenOn(boolean)) from API level 27 onwards.

Comment: Thank you.  This information is very useful.

Comment: this didnt work on Huawei but thank it worked until i addded more FLAGS like @rubmz mentioned  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON

Answer (score 11):

Code

```
 PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock  wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
            PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
            PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "appname::WakeLock");

    //acquire will turn on the display
    wakeLock.acquire();

    //release will release the lock from CPU, in case of that, screen will go back to sleep mode in defined time bt device settings
    wakeLock.release();
```

in the Manifest file, the permission should be

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```